# asp.net MVC4 selecteditem in dropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

How to set selecteditem in a dropdownList when editing a record?  Please help me!

The below is the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
 {          
     ViewModel model = GetViewModel(id);

     return View(model);
 }
```

The below is the view:

```
@model ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}


<h2>Edit/Copy Request</h2>
<h3></h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Requests</legend>

        <div class="float-left">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Crop)
            @Html.DropDownList("CropList", string.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Crop)

        </div>

        <div class="float-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stage)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Stage)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Stage)

        </div>

    </fieldset>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Change" />
    </p>

}
```

The "CropList" is a selectList that is part of the ViewModel.
@Html.DropDownList("CropList", string.Empty)  would get the selection list for the dropdown box.  However, how to get set selectedItem of the dropdown box?  It is easy with textbox:
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Crop);

Hugh

Answer (score 1):

put it in a drop down list for instead.  for helpers tie items to the model

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CropList, SelectList)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Matt, for your help.  It is easy once you know how.

Comment: Thanks very much, Matt, for your help.  It is easy once you know how to do it.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you :).  would you mind marking my answer as the correct one?